# Powershell: write permissions to subfolder

Tags: windows, server, permissions, copy, ntfs

Im trying to set deny permissions to a bunch of folders, the folder struckture looks like this:

```
mainfolder
 testuser1
  subfolder 1
  subfolder 2
  subfolder 3
  subfolder 4
 testuser2
  subfolder 1
  subfolder 2
  subfolder 3
  subfolder 4
 testuser3
  subfolder 1
  subfolder 2
  subfolder 3
  subfolder 4
```

i need to write te permissions to subfolder 2
I have a template folder with all the sub folder with the right permissions
the names of the subfolders are exactly the same for every user.
how can i use a loop with icacls to do this? meby robocopy copy:o ?